# Registering Facebook login users with aws-amplify.js

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, amazon-cognito-facebook

I configured both User Pool and Identity Pool in AWS Cognito manually. In User Pool, I’ve entered Facebook app ID, App secret, Authorize scope (public_profile and email), and then in Identity Pool, I entered User Pool ID and App client id for Cognito, and Facebook App ID for Facebook authentication.

When user logs in using facebook, amplify authenticates without a problem, but it doesn’t create user in User Pool, if the user is a new user. Is there any way to configure amplify in a way that it registers users logging on using Facebook in User Pool if they don’t exist there?

Or can I create user in User Pool programmatically?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49984024/aws-cognito-amplify-have-new-user-sign-ups-be-automatically-add-to-a-user-grou?rq=1

Comment: Hi Rahul, do you know how we point to that lambda function? In Federated Identities, under Facebook, Cognito Events -> Sync Trigger? I did this, but the lambda function never triggered.

Comment: nope sorry i don't know about that.

Comment: @AhmetCetin by configuring the lambda to user pool triggers section